# A possible generalization of Gauss Lucas theorem to higher dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

A real half space in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is $$\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2\mid \phi(z,w) > \lambda\}$$ where $\lambda$ is a real number and $\phi$ is a $\mathbb{R}$- linear functional from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Assume that $p(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ has all its roots in a real half space $K$. Is it true that all critical points of $p$ must necessarily lie in $K$?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @geocalc33  As trivial example $z=0$.There is no critical point.

Comment: The real half space is $Re(z)>-1$

Comment: You might be able to use a convex space argument here because the real half space is a convex set. Given a set $X,$ a convexity over $X$ is a collection $$ of subsets of X satisfying the $(X, ).$ It's hard to refine the convex sets in question in higher dimensions. I would suggest reading this paper, which delves into generalisations of Gauss Lucas: researchgate.net/publication/221966131_Multivariate_Gauss-Lucas_Theorems

Comment: and this: [4] A. W. Goodman: Remarks on the Gauss-Lucas theorem in higher dimensional space,Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 55 (1976), 97–12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very pretty multivariate extension of Gauss-Lucas proved by Marek Kanter [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6426) As far as I can tell, the paper has not been published, but the proof of the main theorem is half a page, so...